# Is there a way to create legend subgroups in Plotly (Python)?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have several datasets that I'm graphing in Plotly, and I can't quite get it to do what I want.  The data is organized something like this:

1. Location A

- Year 1, Winter
- Year 1, Summer
- Year 2, Winter
- Year 2, Summer

2. Location B

- Year 1, Winter
- Year 1, Summer
- Year 2, Winter
- Year 2, Summer

I've created legend groups for both locations similar to this:

```
A1W=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocA', name='Year1 Winter')
A1S=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocA', name='Year1 Summer')
A2W=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocA', name='Year2 Winter')
A2S=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocA', name='Year2 Summer')

B1W=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocB', name='Year1 Winter')
B1S=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocB', name='Year1 Summer')
B2W=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocB', name='Year2 Winter')
B2S=go.Scatter(..., legendgroup='LocB', name='Year2 Summer')
```

This gives me two legend groups with four markers in each.  But what I'd like is to group winters and summers separately in each location, so that each location  group would show one marker for "Winter, both years" and one for "Summer, both years." Then, if I set groupclick to 'toggleitem', I should be able to toggle all Winter data or all Summer data in a given location with one click.  Is this something that can be done?

The only thing I could think of was to create the legend groups as "LocA Winter", "LocA Summer", "LocB Winter", etc. but that gives me four separate groups which isn't really what I want.